# Tailing named pipe in Docker to write to stdout

Tags: php, docker, stdout, named-pipes

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

# Install dependencies, etc

RUN \
    && mkfifo /tmp/stdout \
    && chmod 777 /tmp/stdout

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

as you can see I'm creating a named pipe at `/tmp/stdout`. And my `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some run-time configuration stuff...

exec "./my-app" "$@" | tail -f /tmp/stdout
```

My PHP application (an executable named `my-app`) writes its application logs to `/tmp/stdout`. I want those logs to then be captured by Docker so that I can do `docker logs <container_id>` and see the logs that the application wrote to `/tmp/stdout`. I am attempting to do this by running the `my-app` command and then tailing `/tmp/stdout`, which will then output the logs to `stdout`.

What I'm seeing happen is that when I run my application, it hangs when it writes the first log message. I believe this happens because there is nothing "reading" from the named pipe, and writing to a named pipe blocks until something reads from it. This is confirmed if I do `docker exec -it <container_id> bash`, and then do `tail -f /tmp/stdout` myself inside the container. Once I do that, the container immediately exits because the application has written its logs to the named pipe.

For reasons that I won't bloat this post with, it's not possible for `my-app` itself to write logs to `stdout`. It has to use `/tmp/stdout`.

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working, and what I need to change? I expect I have to change the `exec` call in `docker-entrypoint.sh`, but I'm not sure how. Thank you!

Comment: I liked your solution. I guess there is an issue with your `my-app` because following Dockerfile is working well.
```FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y iputils-ping
CMD ping 4.2.2.4 > out | tail -f out```

Comment: Does any of the answers to [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm seeing happen is that when I run my application, it hangs when it writes the first log message. I believe this happens because there is nothing "reading" from the named pipe, and writing to a named pipe blocks until something reads from it.

This is correct, see [`fifo(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). But with your example code

```sh
exec "./my-app" "$@" | tail -f /tmp/stdout
```

this should actually work since the pipe will start `./my-app` and `tail` simultaneously so that there *is* something reading from `/tmp/stdout`.

But one problem here is that `tail -f` will never terminate by itself and so neither your `docker-entrypoint.sh`/container. You could fix this with:

```sh
tail --pid=$$ -f /tmp/stdout &
exec "./my-app" "$@"
```

`tail --pid` will terminate as soon as the process provided by id terminates where `$$` is the pid of the `bash` process (and through `exec` later the pid of `./my-app`).

---

> For reasons that I won't bloat this post with, it's not possible for `my-app` itself to write logs to `stdout`. It has to use `/tmp/stdout`.

Does this mean it has to write to a filesystem *path* or is the path `/tmp/stdout` hardcoded?

If you can use any path you can use `/dev/stdout` / `/proc/self/fd/1` / `/proc/$$/fd/1` as logging path to let your application write to `stdout`.

If `/tmp/stdout` is hardcoded try symlinking it to `/dev/stdout`:

```sh
ln -s /dev/stdout /tmp/stdout
```

Comment: Correct, it's hard-coded. Symlinking /tmp/stdout to /dev/stdout actually worked really well and is much more elegant than what I was attempting. Thank you!